# How do I set the resize-behaviour of subplots?

Tags: matplotlib, resize, subplot

I'm working with several subplots in a window. Just after plotting it looks great, problem is when I rezise the windows manually. The subplots do not adapt correctly to the new size of the window. How can I fix that?

Window after plotting, looking great:
[image]

window after resizing it manually, looks bad:
[image]

EDIT:

A simply demo-Code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

figure(figsize=(24,6))

subplot(131)
ylabel("test")
plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plot([3,2,1], label="test2")

subplot(132)
ylabel("test")
plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plot([3,2,1], label="test2")


subplot(133)
ylabel("test")
plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plot([3,2,1], label="test2")

tight_layout()
show()
```

As you see, the plot looks good after plotting it. But when you start to shrink the plot horizontally, the space between plot and plot gets smaller and smaller. And at the end, the ticklabels are on others plots, because there's no space for them. I need to know how to set that the entire plot gets smaller, leving space for the labels.

Comment: please provide the code to repeat the situation.

Comment: the code consists of 4 files... its to complicated to post it here. In the next hours I will post an eaysier code with the same problem...

Comment: allright, posted an demo-code, I think it demonstrates my problem

Comment: Looks like an issue with resizing + aspect ratio.  As you make the window narrower also make it shorter.

Comment: Try to run it in interactive mode, then everytime you resize it and are not happy with it, you can use `tight_layout()` to reposition the labels correctly. Not a real solution, but works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not exactly the answer of my question, but it solves my problem:

After creating the figure, you connect the resize-event to an eventhandler:
`cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', onresize)`

```
def onresize(event):
    plt.tight_layout()
```

As Wicket said, I'm just calling `tight_layout()` again and again, but automatically.

Comment: OMG! This is gold! Thanks!